# jQuery and html same page

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hey guys so basically I want the output to stay on the same page. I don't know anything about jQuery and was hoping I could get some help!

> EDIT: Sorry to not confuse anyone the code below is for my original
>   code. Now I want to incorporate jQuery and keep it on the same page
>   instead of using php.

So basically my code is:

```
<h1>Flybai-Knight Automotive</h1>
<h2> Payroll Processing </h2>
<p>Inputs:</p>
<ul>
    <form action="processed.php" method="post">
        <li>
            Employee: <input name="name" type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
            Status 
            <input name="choice" type="radio" value="Married"> Married
            <input name="choice" type="radio" value="Not married" checked> Not Married 
        </li>
        <li>
            Hours worked 
            <select name="hours">
                <option value=20>20 hours</option>
                <option value=25>25 hours</option>
                <option value=30>30 hours</option>
                <option value=35>35 hours</option>
                <option value=40>40 hours</option>
                <option value=45>45 hours</option>
                <option value=50>50 hours</option>
            </li>    
        </select><br>
        <li>
            Wage 
            <select name="wage">
                <option value=10>$10.00 per hour</option>
                <option value=10.50>$10.50 per hour</option>
                <option value=11>$11.00 per hour</option>
                <option value=11.50>$11.50 per hour</option>
                <option value=12>$12.00 per hour</option>
                <option value=12.50>$12.50 per hour</option>
                <option value=13>$13.00 per hour</option>
                <option value=13.50>$13.50 per hour</option>
                <option value=14>$14.00 per hour</option>
                <option value=14.50>$14.50 per hour</option>
                <option value=15>$15.00 per hour</option>
            </li>
        </select><br>
    </ul>

    Outputs:<br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate Net Pay">
</form>
```

I want the output to be something like:

> Net pay for 100.00 is $180.00, based upon 20 hours worked, a wage of $10.00 per hour, and a tax rate of 10%

My code for the other page is:
Edited my php code to actually work.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $choice = $_POST["choice"];
    +$hours = $_POST["hours"];
    +$wage = $_POST["wage"];
    if ($choice == "Married") {
      +$tax = 0.10;
    } else {
        +$tax = 0.20;    
    }
    if ($choice == "Married") {
        $taxView = 10;
    } else {
        $taxView = 20;  
    }

    +$netPay = ($wage * $hours) * $tax;
    +$netPayFinal = ($wage * $hours) - $netPay;
    $result =  "Net pay for ". $name. " is $" . $netPayFinal. ", based upon " . $hours." hours worked, a wage of $" . $wage. " per hour, and a tax rate of " . $taxView."%";
    echo $result;die;
?>
```

I don't want it on another page. Thanks for helping in advance!

Comment: Note that you have a couple issues in your HTML which is making it invalid, ie. a `form` as a child of a `ul`, and closing the `select` and `li` in the rong order. I'd strongly suggest you fix those.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is an asynchronous call. Thats called ajax and you can do this with jquery.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    data: serialize(#yourForm),
    url: "url-to-your-file.php",
    Success: function(result)
    {
      // Do what you want with the result
    }
 });
 </script>
```

I recommend to you to read further on this topic.

I will add a Link
[Here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Using this you will get answer on same page :

index.php

```
    <form action="" id="myForm" method="post">

    <li>Employee:<input name="name" type="text"></li>
    <li>Status <input name="choice" type="radio" value="Married"> Married
        <input name="choice" type="radio" value="Not married" checked> Not Married </li>
    <li>Hours worked <select name="hours">
    <option value=20>20 hours</option>
    <option value=25>25 hours</option>
    <option value=30>30 hours</option>
    <option value=35>35 hours</option>
    <option value=40>40 hours</option>
    <option value=45>45 hours</option>
    <option value=50>50 hours</option></li></select><br>

    <li>Wage <select name="wage">
    <option value=10>$10.00 per hour</option>
    <option value=10.50>$10.50 per hour</option>
    <option value=11>$11.00 per hour</option>
    <option value=11.50>$11.50 per hour</option>
    <option value=12>$12.00 per hour</option>
    <option value=12.50>$12.50 per hour</option>
    <option value=13>$13.00 per hour</option>
    <option value=13.50>$13.50 per hour</option>
    <option value=14>$14.00 per hour</option>
      <option value=14.50>$14.50 per hour</option>
      <option value=15>$15.00 per hour</option></li></select><br></ul>

    Outputs:<br><br>

    <input type="button" onclick="getData();" value="Calculate Net Pay">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getData(){
            var myFormData = $('#myForm').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'processed.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data : myFormData,
                    success: function(result) {
                        alert(result);
                    },
                });
        }
    </script>
```

processed.php :

```
    <?php
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $choice = $_POST["choice"];
        $hours = $_POST["hours"];
        $wage = $_POST["wage"];
        if ($choice == "Married") {
          $tax = 0.10;
        } else {
            $tax = 0.20;    
        }
        if ($choice == "Married") {
            $taxView = 10;
        } else {
            $taxView = 20;  
        }

        $netPay = ($wage * $hours) * $choice;
        $result =  "Net pay for " . $name. " is $" . $netPay. ", based upon " . $hours. " hours worked, a wage of $". $wage. " per hour, and a tax rate of " . $taxView. "%";
        echo $result;die;
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! it helped but how would I put it on the same page as in the same header pops up but instead of the form it is replaced with the result line? Example:(on top) Flybai-Knight Automotive (underneath) Payroll Processing (underneath both the top two headers) Net pay for Austin is $180.00, based upon 20 hours worked, a wage of $10.00 per hour, and a tax rate of 10% instead of using an alert.

Comment: Why the die? Why the else tags? Why no sprintf? Why no JSON output?

Comment: just want to keep the file code same as it was...and here $result contains string so no need to json encode.